# Executing a dart application prints errors to console

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

I am using Dart Editor|
Dart Editor version 1.10.0.dev_01_01 (DEV)
Dart SDK version 1.10.0-dev.1.1

I open polymer_snippet and run the app and it executes as expected.

I attempted to run epimss_app but it does not run and displays the following errors to Tools Ouput (console)

```
--- 1:20:06 PM Starting pub serve : polymer_snippet ---
Loading source assets...
The null object does not have a getter 'pubspec'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'pubspec'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
dart:core                                                                                                            Object.noSuchMethod
e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-dev\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub\lib\src\barback\dependency_computer.dart 48    DependencyComputer.DependencyComputer.<fn>
dart:collection                                                                                                      SetMixin.every
e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-dev\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub\lib\src\barback\dependency_computer.dart 47    DependencyComputer.DependencyComputer
e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-dev\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub\lib\src\barback\load_all_transformers.dart 33  loadAllTransformers.<async>
dart:isolate                                                                                                         _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
This is an unexpected error. Please run

    pub --trace 'serve' 'web' '--port' '8080' '--admin-port' '49923' '--hostname' 'localhost'

and include the results in a bug report on http://dartbug.com/new.
```

I tried to run polymer-snippet again with the same result. I closed Dart Editor did a pub cache repair and attempted running either application again with the same result.

The GUI (if dart-eclipse-editor is used) says Error Launching application - Could not start pub serve or connect to pub.

Why is this happening? I would expect to be able to change from one dart app to another and run either without any issues.

Thanks

Comment: Could be http://dartbug.com/21490, or http://dartbug.com/22511, or http://dartbug.com/22041